# SQL - Como listar apenas os registros que apresentam mais de uma tabela filha

Tags: sql

Eu preciso listar os nomes de funcionários que possuem dois ou mais filhos (são listados duas ou mais vezes) no seguinte select, mas não faço ideia de como.

```
select f.NomeFunc as "Funcionário", d.NomeDep as "Filhos"
from Funcionario f
inner join Dependente d
on f.ID_Func = d.ID_func
```

Alguma dica?

Comment: Utilize a cláusula GROUP BY / COUNT juntamente com a cláusula HAVING. A propósito, me parece que utilizou erroneamente a expressão "tabela filha" em sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Para você chegar neste resultado, conforme foi comentado, você precisa primeiro fazer um agrupamento e depois usar o HAVING para filtrar os resultados. Sua consulta ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
select f.NomeFunc as "Funcionário"
from Funcionario f
inner join Dependente d
on f.ID_Func = d.ID_func
GROUP BY f.NomeFunc
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```